# grep with variable using ssh

Tags: ssh, grep

I want to search for the files in a directory which contain both words *wrod1* and *word2*. I use the following when I want to search in the local directory and it works fine:

```
for FILE in pathToDirectory/*.txt; do grep -q word1 $FILE && grep -q word2
 $FILE && echo $FILE; done
```

Since I cannot use variables when working with remote host what should I do instead. I found out from other threads([Remote for-loop over SSH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/remote-for-loop-over-ssh?newreg=583d0d3c73014aab8b935473cdcaf178)) that people use the command for connecting to server and then put the find command in the quote right after. Similar to this:

```
 ssh -l username servername 'for FILE in pathToDirectory/*.txt; do grep -q word1 $FILE && grep -q word2 $FILE && echo $FILE; done'
```

but this still doesn't work for me. 
The command I am running now(still gives me errors):

```
ssh username@servername sh -c 'for FILE in /pathToDirectory/*.txt; do grep -q "word1" "$FILE" && grep -q "word2" "$FILE" && echo "$FILE"; done'
```

Errors

```
FILE: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
FILE: -c: line 0: `for'
FILE: Undefined variable
```

Comment: What error messages do you get? What shell does the server use?

Comment: it uses "tcsh"
it says:
"for: Command not found.
FILE: Undefined variable."

Comment: if you connect through ssh and run the same command, does it work?

Comment: @M4rty No difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the default shell is `tcsh` on the remote host, you may want to explicitly start a `sh` shell:

```
ssh username@servername sh -c 'for FILE in pathToDirectory/*.txt; do grep -q "word1" "$FILE" && grep -q "word2" "$FILE" && echo "$FILE"; done'
```

Note also that you should double quote the `$FILE` variable expansion to cope with filenames that have exotic characters in them.

Also note that although you use `word1` and `word2` with `grep`, these are *regular expressions* and not *words*.  To look for words in a file, use `grep -wF "word"`.

---

It seems as if `ssh` will always run the login shell to execute the given command on the remote host, and if this is `tcsh` it is *really difficult* to get the quoting right in the command line script.

Two solutions (and I'm not fond of either):

1. Change the login shell on the remote host to a `sh`-like shell like `bash`, `ksh`, or `zsh`.  Do this by logging in on the host and run `chsh`.
2. Put the script in a script file and execute it through `ssh` with

   ```
   ssh username@servername sh ./script.sh
   ```

Comment: Thanks I did the above as you mentioned , still working on the errors I get:
"FILE: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
FILE: -c: line 0: `for'
FILE: Undefined variable."

Comment: @april Huh? What Unix is the machine you're connecting to running?

Comment: @april Do quote the `word1` and `word2` strings too. If the words contain special characters, you will have problems.

Comment: Linux x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: yes I quote the words but now have these errors: "for: Command not found.
FILE: Undefined variable."

Comment: @april That's what I'd expect you to get with the `tcsh` or `csh` shells. Did you forget the `sh -c` part?

Comment: no I didn't forget to put sh -c

Comment: @april Are you by any chance using _single_ quotes inside the command? The only single quotes on the command line should be the ones encapsulating the for loop.

Comment: No I don't, but I do have underscore(_) and star(*) and slash(/) inside my pathfile. could that be a problem? should they preceded by backslash or no?

Comment: @april "pathfile"? Could you update the question with the exact command you're trying to run?

Comment: I updated the question, yes I mean inside pathToDirectory I have directory name with underscore

Comment: @april That should not be a problem. I'll try getting some friends of min to look at this too.

Comment: @april I finally managed to reproduce exactly what you are seeing. Are you able to change your login shell on the remote machine to something like `/bin/bash`?

Comment: @april Another solution would be to put the shell code in a script on the remote host and run that through `ssh`.

Comment: yes thanks it worked! As you said I just put the shell code in a script file and run it, thanks again